# Do AWS MSK bootstrap server names resolve with public DNS servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-msk

We have an MSK cluster setup. I know the bootstrap server names which look something like `b-3.abcd-dev-kafka-dev.lq2z7z.c4.kafka.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` (name changed).

These servers are supposed to be sitting in my subnet and as such I'd expect them to be only resolvable in my internal network. However, the DNS names seem to also resolve when doing a `dig <name> 1.1.1.1` i.e. a request to cloudflares DNS servers. Is this a normal behavior of AWS MSK clusters or is there a DNS leak somewhere that I'd need to fix?

Comment: Hi @pascalwhoop , we are facing issue, were you able to find a resolution for this.

Answer (score 1):

No matter the cluster is private or public, all **.amazonaws.com** dns are publicly resolvable.

They do will point to some private IP and their use will make sense only for you.
If other people resolve this name from another private network, it will point to some resources on their network.

These names have some random strings that make them hard to find out anyway.

Comment: can you add a source to your comment? Then I'll qualify it as the right answer. The statement makes sense to me but a reference to an official amazon document would be ideal.